# Google form automatically run script everytime user open form

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-forms

i'm making a form for making an appointment, in this form user can select date available and i have a script that update the date choices everyday from spreadsheet but the script doesn't automatically run when someone open/fill in the form so the date choices doesn't change automatically. I need to run the script everytime to update the choices

anybody know how to make google script automatically run/update everytime the form is open by a user/customer ?

here is the form (so this date choices is from spreadsheet and the spreadsheet update everyday, but when i open the form it doesn't automatically change/update)

this is the sheet where the choices are from
[image]

[image]

and this is my script code (the code work fine but just doesn't update automatically to the form)

```
var ssID = "1hil07Z2wvTXH1szX9bNfPKVLDQVO36ACQFGOU6_VUI0";
var formID="1SD5BenAnNxNz-wtw0YPut6YdTf7a62zHn_z3VrTdTUU";

var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("DATA");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function main(){

var labels = wsData.getRange(1,1,1,wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

labels.forEach(function(label,i){
 var options =  wsData
 .getRange(2, i+1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1)
 .getDisplayValues()
 .map(function(o){return o[0]})
 .filter(function(o){return o !== ""});
//Logger.log(options);
updateDropDownUsingTitle(label,options);

});

}



function updateDropDownUsingTitle(title,values) {
var title = "Tanggal Penjemputan";
var items = form.getItems();
var titles = items.map(function(item){
return item.getTitle();

});
var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
var item = items[pos];
var itemID = item.getId();

updateDropdown(itemID,values);
}

function updateDropdown(id,values) {

var item = form.getItemById(id);
item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
}
```

Comment: There is no interactive programmatic access to a running Google Form via apps script.  If you want interactive access to a form them you will need to create a webapp.  The only programmatic access with Google Forms starts at the point of submission. And you can also update choices via code written in the form editor before a form is activated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Cooper is right. Script can only be running when someone open the form Editor, by which you can make it happen using onOpen event. Not the user open the form link.

But here is a workaround you can get. It depends on the values you want to set.
If the data is updates by daily , you can simply add a trigger to update the date value by day or hour.
if the data is needed to be updated by the remain time&date slot, you can use on form Submit trigger.  Each time when user submit a respond (a date will be deleted from spreadsheet. The remain date can be updated to the form.

```
function update(){
  const values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id').getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  let item_id;
  form.getItems().filter(r => {
    if(r.getTitle() == 'Test1'){
        item_id = r.getId();
    }
  });
  form.getItemById(item_id).asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
  console.log(values)
}
```

[image]

[image]